# When to set up a nondefault VPC in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

When creating an EC2 instance *(or some other kind of stuff)* on AWS, there appears a default VPC.

Also, as another option, a VPC can be created beforehand and selected during the EC2 instance creation etc..

So, in which use cases should we **create a new VPC instead of using the default one**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html) does a pretty good job describing how they create the default VPC.

> When we create a default VPC, we do the following to set it up for
>   you:
>
> - Create a VPC with a size /16 IPv4 CIDR block (172.31.0.0/16). This provides up to 65,536 private IPv4 addresses.
> - Create a size /20 default subnet in each Availability Zone. This provides up to 4,096 addresses per subnet, a few of which are reserved
>     for our use.
> - Create an internet gateway and connect it to your default VPC.
> - Create a main route table for your default VPC with a rule that sends all IPv4 traffic destined for the internet to the internet
>     gateway.
> - Create a default security group and associate it with your default VPC.
> - Create a default network access control list (ACL) and associate it with your default VPC.
> - Associate the default DHCP options set for your AWS account with your default VPC.

This is great with simple applications and proof of concepts, but not for productions deployments. A DB instance should for example not be publicly available, and should there for be placed in a private subnet, something the default VPC does not have. You would then create some sort of backend instance that would connect to the DB and expose a REST interface to the public.

Another reason may be if you are running multiple environments (DEV, QA, PROD) that are all copies of each other. In this case you would want them to be totally isolated from each other as to not risk a bad deployment in the DEV environment to accidentally affect the PROD environment.

The list can go on with other reasons, and there are probably some that are better than those that I have presented you with today.

Comment: Decent. So, do you mean the idea can be sumed up primarily on two categories: for intranet structures and multiple environment levels?

Comment: I guess you could say that they are two use cases that I came up with off the top of my head. Another might be that you want to setup a bastion host that gives access to resources that are only available through tunneling with SSH. The end goal for all projects is access control, and a resource should only have access to what it needs to work. Placing a bunch of EC2 instances in public subnets will not provide this.

Comment: @PhilipLaine quick question, even if your RDS is in a public subnet you can add a security group to only allow certain inbound traffic. Why would something like that not suffice for production? It just seems to my naive mind that all these subnets, security groups, NACLS add more overhead ...?

Answer (score 2):

If you understand VPC reasonably well, then **you should always create your own VPC**. This is because you have full control over the structure.

I suspect that the primary reason for providing a *Default VPC* is so that people can launch an Amazon EC2 instance without having to understand VPCs first.